# Maven - depend on multi-module aggregator project

Tags: java, spring, maven

I've got a multi-module maven project, with a structure like:

```
projectA-parent
  - module-1
  - module-2
```

And I have another project where I want to bring in all the modules in `projectA-parent` as runtime dependencies (it's a Spring application, and each module in `projectA-parent` contains Spring services that I want to be able to autowire).

What I'd like to do is something like

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>projectA-group</groupId>
    <artifactId>projectA-parent</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

so that if I add another module to `projectA-parent` it is automatically brought in as a runtime dependency (i.e., I don't want to have to add each new module as a dependency in my Spring application as I add them). Is such a thing possible?

Answer (score 3):

You will have to use

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
     <groupId>projectA-parent-groupId</groupId>
     <artifactId>projectA-parent-artifactId</artifactId>
     <type>pom</type>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

This will transitively add all dependencies declared in com.my:commons-deps to your current POM.

Using

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>...</groupId>
            <artifactId>...</artifactId>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

works as a simple 'include' of artifacts versions in your dependency management. Thus, it won't add any dependency in your project.

**UPDATE:**

Another aprroach would be to use a BOM (Bill of Materials). Check this [link](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) for the usage of `BOM`. It is hidden somewhere at the bottom.

You can create a BOM that lists all your modules as dependencies and then you can include the BOM into your pom.xml like this:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>your_bom_group_id</groupId>
            <artifactId>your_bom_artifact_id</artifactId>
            <version>you_bom_version</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: The problem is that the modules aren't dependencies of `projectA-parent`, but sub-modules. My current solution (which might be the best/only option) is to have a "BOM" module that lists all the other modules as dependencies, then import this BOM as a type:pom/scope:import dependency, as in your answer. The dependencies are marked as scope:runtime in the BOM pom.xml.

Answer (score 3):

I guess I'd just add another module that referred to the other modules in your project, e.g.:

```
projectA-parent
  - module-1
  - module-2
  - module-deps
```

with `module-deps` as a jar or pom that depends on `module-1` and `module-2`.
You'll have to update `module-deps` as you add more modules, but at least it's only in one place.