# How to include the modules in a top-level POM in another project?

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, pom.xml

I've googled and stack-overflowed everything, but maybe not enough as I'm still not clear how one adds a module of a Maven project as a dependency in another.

So for example let's say we've got:

```
MajorPager
  |___ POM.xml
  |___ chuck-commons-core
  |    |____POM.xml
  |____rajni-commons-core
       |____POM.xml
```

Now I want to add `chuck-commons-core` but not `rajni-commons-core`. If I do it directly, it can't find the module. So I ran across the following discussions on stack-overflow and my old friend Guggal:

In summary, the below discussions talk of how to create multi-module projects but not really how to include the sub-modules in a top-level POM into another project.

#### Useful discussions for context

- [`SO` Adding a reference to a parent POM project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19395973/maven-adding-a-reference-to-a-parent-pom-project)
- [`SO` How to add a parent POM as dependency to a different maven project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43331526/adding-parent-pom-as-a-dependency-to-a-different-maven-project)
- [`SO` Adding a reference to Parent POM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19395973/maven-adding-a-reference-to-a-parent-pom-project)
- [`SO` Maven Parent POM vs Modules POM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992213/maven-parent-pom-vs-modules-pom)
- [`SO` Depend on multi-module aggregator project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43204378/maven-depend-on-multi-module-aggregator-project)
- [`SO` How to add dependency in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9164893/how-do-i-add-a-maven-dependency-in-eclipse)
- [`SO` How do I configure Maven multi-module-dependency on sub project with different package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48860053/how-to-configure-maven-multi-module-dependency-on-sub-project-with-different-pac)
- [`SO` How to add a module in parent projects POM as dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14960005/maven-how-to-add-a-module-in-parent-projects-pom-as-dependency)
- [`SO` How to add a dependency in Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396245/add-a-dependency-in-maven)
- [`Maven` dependency mechanism](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html)
- [`Maven` POM aggregation](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Aggregation)
- [`Baeldung` Multi-module project](https://www.baeldung.com/maven-multi-module)
- [`Codetab` Maven multi-module](http://www.codetab.org/tutorial/apache-maven/multi-module/multi-module-project/)
- [`Howtodoinjava` Maven parent child POM example](https://howtodoinjava.com/maven/maven-parent-child-pom-example/)
- [`Mastertheboss` Maven multi-module tutorial](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-frameworks/maven-tutorials/jboss-maven/maven-multi-module-tutorial?showall=&start=1)
- [`Codetab` Multi-module hierarchical project](http://www.codetab.org/tutorial/apache-maven/multi-module/hierarchical-project/)
- [`Sonatype` How to share resources across projects](https://blog.sonatype.com/2008/04/how-to-share-resources-across-projects-in-maven/)
- [`Spring` Multi-module project](https://spring.io/guides/gs/multi-module/)

Concretely, I'd just like a summary from an expert how they add a sub-module of a Parent POM as a dependency to another project.

Comment: Maybe I did not understand you correctly, but if you have a module `chuck-commons-core`, then it has groupId, artifactId and version. You can reference it from other projects as a normal dependency using the groupId, artifact and version.

Answer (score 0):

As of now, I think this is the best solution - to add the following ccodee to the POM.xml of the `MajorPager`.

*Code block 1 incoming*

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.teachme.how</groupId>
            <artifactId>MajorPager</artifactId>
            <version>0.6-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

*Code block 2 incoming*

```
<dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.teachme.how</groupId>
        <artifactId>norris-commons-core</artifactId>
        <version>0.6</version>
    </dependency>
    ...
</dependencies>
```

When you do so enables Maven to find out where the dependency are - and so Maven picks them up with `mvn clean -U install` or `mvn package -U -DskipTests`. And I should like to be educated if this isn't the most effective pattern. Or if any of the fields above are optional that Maven doesn't want me to specify because it can derive it on it's own (say for example, `version` tag?) - please let me know if that's case as well.

Comment: Using the import scope for the MajorPager will only work if in MajorPager the dependencies have been defined via dependencyManagement otherwise not.